# Reading a Line From File Without Advancing [Pythonic Approach]

Tags: python

What's a pythonic approach for reading a line from a file but not advancing where you are in the file?

For example, if you have a file of

```
cat1
cat2
cat3
```

and you do `file.readline()` you will get `cat1\n` . The next `file.readline()` will return `cat2\n` .

Is there some functionality like `file.some_function_here_nextline()` to get `cat1\n` then you can later do `file.readline()` and get back `cat1\n`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no builtin functionality for this, but such a function is easy to write, since most Python `file` objects support `seek` and `tell` methods for jumping around within a file. So, the process is very simple:

- Find the current position within the file using `tell`.
- Perform a `read` (or `write`) operation of some kind.
- `seek` back to the previous file pointer.

This allows you to do nice things like read a chunk of data from the file, analyze it, and then potentially overwrite it with different data. A simple wrapper for the functionality might look like:

```
def peek_line(f):
    pos = f.tell()
    line = f.readline()
    f.seek(pos)
    return line

print peek_line(f) # cat1
print peek_line(f) # cat1
```

---

You could implement the same thing for other `read` methods just as easily. For instance, implementing the same thing for `file.read`:

```
def peek(f, length=1):
    pos = f.tell()
    data = f.read(length) # Might try/except this line, and finally: f.seek(pos)
    f.seek(pos)
    return data

print peek(f, 4) # cat1
print peek(f, 4) # cat1
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It return `OSError: telling position disabled by next() call`

Answer (score 5):

You could use wrap the file up with [itertools.tee](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) and get back two iterators, bearing in mind the caveats stated in the documentation

For example

```
from itertools import tee
import contextlib
from StringIO import StringIO
s = '''\
cat1
cat2
cat3
'''

with contextlib.closing(StringIO(s)) as f:
  handle1, handle2 = tee(f)
  print next(handle1)
  print next(handle2)

 cat1
 cat1
```

Comment: Nice approach; definitely meets the OP's "Pythonic" request. My only concern would be what to do if a larger (perhaps arbitrary) number of "reads" is required? Just increasing the number of iterators seems like it would get messy very quickly.

Comment: Responding to my own concern, I guess you could keep one handle as the "base" and keep recreating/teeing off that as needed: `basehandle, readfromme = tee(f) print next(readfromme) basehandle, readfromme = tee(basehandle) print next(readfromme)`. A little ugly but maybe useful depending on the application.

Comment: @HenryKeiter, if it is known that no more than `x` "seen" lines would be needed at arbitrary times, one option involves populating an `x`-sized [deque](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) with each line as it is read and using it as a buffer

Comment: @1_CR Sure. I'm more concerned with the case where it *isn't* known how many times a certain chunk of the file might need to be read. Of course it may be better to use a single `f.readlines()` in that case, or store the data some other way, but hey.

Answer (score 4):

The [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) library offers a `peekable` class that allows you to `peek()` ahead without advancing an iterable.

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    p = mit.peekable(f.readlines())

p.peek()
# 'cat1\n'

next(p)
# 'cat1\n'
```

We can view the next line before calling `next()` to advance the iterable `p`. We can now view the next line by calling `peek()` again.

```
p.peek()
# 'cat2\n'
```

See also the [`more_itertools` docs](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.peekable), as `peekable` allows you to `prepend()` items to an iterable before advancing as well.

Answer (score 3):

Solutions with `tell()`/`seek()` will not work with `stdin` and other iterators. More generic implementation can be as simple as this:

```
class lookahead_iterator(object):
    __slots__ = ["_buffer", "_iterator", "_next"]
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self._buffer = [] 
        self._iterator = iter(iterable)
        self._next = self._iterator.next
    def __iter__(self):
        return self 
    def _next_peeked(self):
        v = self._buffer.pop(0)
        if 0 == len(self._buffer):
            self._next = self._iterator.next
        return v
    def next(self):
        return self._next()
    def peek(self):
        v = next(self._iterator)
        self._buffer.append(v)
        self._next = self._next_peeked
        return v
```

Usage:

```
with open("source.txt", "r") as lines:
    lines = lookahead_iterator(lines)
    magic = lines.peek()
    if magic.startswith("#"):
        return parse_bash(lines)
    if magic.startswith("/*"):
        return parse_c(lines)
    if magic.startswith("//"):
        return parse_cpp(lines)
    raise ValueError("Unrecognized file")
```

Answer (score 2):

Manually doing it is not that hard:

```
f = open('file.txt')
line = f.readline()
print line
>>> cat1
# the calculation is: - (length of string + 1 because of the \n)
# the second parameter is needed to move from the actual position of the buffer
f.seek((len(line)+1)*-1, 1)
line = f.readline()
print line
>>> cat1
```

You can wrap this in a method like this:

```
def lookahead_line(file):
    line = file.readline()
    count = len(line) + 1
    file.seek(-count, 1)
    return file, line
```

And use it like this:

```
f = open('file.txt')
f, line = lookahead_line(f)
print line
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Does not work for me: `io.UnsupportedOperation: can't do nonzero cur-relative seeks`