# reading the next line in a text document

Tags: python, python-3.5

Hello I'm trying to make an live info screen to a school project,
I'm reading through a file which does a lot of different thing which depending of what line it's reading.

```
dclist = []
interface = ""
vrfmem = ""

db = sqlite3.connect('data/main.db')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('''SELECT r1 FROM routers''')
all_rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in all_rows:
    dclist.append(row[0])


for items in dclist:
    f = open('data/'+ items + '.txt', 'r+')
    for line in f:
        if 'interface Vlan' in line:
            interface = re.search(r'(?<=\interface Vlan).*', line).group(0)

        if 'vrf member' in line.next():
            vrfmem = interface = re.search(r'(?<=\vrf member).*', line).group(0)
        else:
            vrfmem = "default"

        if 'ip address' in line:
            print(items + interface + vrfmem + "ip her" )
    db.commit()
    db.close()
```

As seen in the code, every line in my document i want to check the next line because if it matches a certain string, i set a variable.

from what i could read myself to, python has a built in function next() that is suppost to be able to do the job for me. But when i run my code im presented with `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'next'

`

Answer (score 0):

[`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) should be called on a file object (`f` in your case), not a string (`line`).

Python knows the current position of `f`, so `f.next()` will automatically read the line following `line`.

Note that this will influence the `for line in f` loop : this loop will skip every other line, the one returned by `f.next()`.

With this `test.txt` file :

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

This code :

```
with open('test.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        print line, file.next()
```

returns :

```
1
2

3
4

5
6
```

If this is not the desired behaviour, you could look at this [thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16840747/6419007)

Comment: if i'm putting .next() on the f varible in this case, how will i tell it, it's the next line of the line it's currently reading

Answer (score 0):

you can hold your previous line in a helper string. (note, I'm using previous/current instead of current/next)

```
dclist = []
interface = ""
vrfmem = ""

db = sqlite3.connect('data/main.db')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('''SELECT r1 FROM routers''')
all_rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in all_rows:
    dclist.append(row[0])


for items in dclist:
    f = open('data/'+ items + '.txt', 'r+')
    currLine = f.readline()
    while line != '':
        prevLine = currLine
        currLine = f.readline()
        if 'interface Vlan' in prevLine :
            interface = re.search(r'(?<=\interface Vlan).*', line).group(0)

        if 'vrf member' in currLine:
            vrfmem = interface = re.search(r'(?<=\vrf member).*', line).group(0)
        else:
            vrfmem = "default"

        if 'ip address' in prevLine:
            print(items + interface + vrfmem + "ip her" )
    db.commit()
    db.close()
```