# pandas read_csv skip rows of unwanted descriptions and blank lines till the real data part

Tags: python, pandas

I have many csv files and want to read in. I want to skip the beginning rows till the line begins with real data. My files happen to begin with certain string like "OPQ" or "BST". The files look like:

```
"This is a new record.
 There are some missing data.
 The test condition is 60 degree"

OPQ  , 11  , speed , -3 , 20
BST  , 20  , speed , 4  , 10
....
```

The first several lines are varying. Just want to skip the first several rows which might be 3 lines or more  descriptions and then several lines of blank lines. The data begins from the line begin with "OPQ" or "BST".
pandas.read_csv skiprows only skip a predefined number of rows which does not work for my case.

Thanks.

Comment: tried skip_rows it will automatically skip the predefined n rows and blank lines. My problem is the rows I need to skip are changing.

Comment: edit my questions to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this in the following manner -

```
my_cols = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"] #You will need to add all column names here since your data is not uniform

df = pd.read_csv("YOUR_CSV_HERE.csv", names=my_cols, engine='python')

start_val= "OPQ"

start_index = df.A[df.A == start_val].index.tolist()[0]
df1 = df.iloc[start_index:, :]
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
```

`df1` should have all your data including and after the row that contains the value "OPQ" with all its indexes reset.

What this snippet basically does is -

- sets up expected column names
- makes a daframe based on your csv with `NaN` for missing values in expected columns
- goes through the dataframe to find the index of the row you want to start from (by finding a specific value in a specific column)
- splits the datafram based on this index and reindexes the new dataframe

Comment: I don't think this will work as df = pd.read_csv("YOUR_CSV_HERE.csv", names=my_cols, engine='python') won't even pass.  
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 8, saw 12

Comment: @newleaf wait a second what exactly are your 2 lines ? (for setting up my_cols) and the line you call to read the csv ? seems like your `read_csv` is getting a lot more arguments than it should

Comment: My files do not have header.Just want to try your method. I tried header = no. If pd.read_csv() does not skip the first several unwanted description, it will return such error.

Comment: @newleaf does your line specify the python engine ? Since I tried that same snippet on my machine with a dummy CSV and it was working without any issues

Answer (score 2):

Pandas will also accept an open file (or file-like) object instead of a filepath. You can use Python to open the file and read the lines you *don't* want until you are at the right place in the file, then Pandas will only process the lines that are left.

```
import pandas as pd

f = open("data.csv")

# Throw away lines of the file until just before the data starts
# In the example the last line before the actual data starts is a blank line
while f.readline() != '\n':
    pass

# Pandas will only process the lines from the current file position onwards
df = pd.read_csv(f, header=None)

# Don't forget to close the file when you're done
f.close()

# Do whatever you want with dataframe here
print(df)
```

I assumed the actual data was separated from the unwanted first part of the text file by a blank line. If you need to actually check the first line of the data, then it is a little trickier, as you will need to [move the file position back after reading the line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840554/reading-a-line-from-file-without-advancing-pythonic-approach).

Comment: My files are comma separated. Tried this method. Somehow the output df somehow assigned 10 columns to the beginning description lines and the data part adjusted to 10 columns make the data part format very strange.

Comment: I've updated my answer to use read_csv. It works for me if you copy-paste the sample data in the question into "data.csv". @newleaf, have you checked that Pandas can read your data if you manually remove the first rows?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using shell commands here. **That way, you can save memory as you do not need to fill the data in memory first**. The method `pd.read_csv()` has param `skiprows` which takes arguments as described below.

> **skiprows** : list-like, int or callable, optional Line numbers to skip
>   (0-indexed) or number of lines to skip (int) at the start of the file.
>
> If callable, the callable function will be evaluated against the row
>   indices, returning True if the row should be skipped and False
>   otherwise. An example of a valid callable argument would be lambda x:
>   x in [0, 2].

You can specify row numbers, but you first need to know what are them. One easiest way would be to get line numbers with the following shell command.

**Process**

Let's say you have data file in `.tsv` format as `data.tsv`

```
OPQ   11  speed  -3  20
BST   20  speed  4   10
OPQ   11  speed  -3  20
BST   20  speed  4   10
```

We want to filter out 1st and 3rd row.

, then you would do

```
$ cat -n data.tsv | grep OPQ | awk '{print $1}' > filter.csv
```

This command writes line numbes where `OPQ` exists to the file called `filter.csv`. So `filter.csv` looks like this

```
1
3
```

Now, we can tell pandas which rows to be skipped.

**Important NOTE:** See the info on `skiprows` parameter stating line numbers (0-indexed), but we have line numbers which are 1-indexed, so we need to change it in the code easily.

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd

filtered_rows = pd.read_csv('./filter.csv', header=None)
filtered_rows[0] = filtered_rows[0] - 1 # assuring to be 0-indexed
filtered_rows = filtered_rows[0].tolist()

data = pd.read_csv('./data.tsv', sep='\t', header=None,
skiprows=filtered_rows)
```

**Output**

```
     0   1      2  3   4
0  BST  20  speed  4  10
1  BST  20  speed  4  10
```

Answer (score 0):

I approached this very differently because the other answers weren't working for me. I set up a simple column search after each read to see if it was found. I picked a column name that was unique so as to be sure it wasn't accidentally finding it in the data above the table:

```
if 'early_date' in df_contents.columns :
   ...
```

In my case I have a ton of CSVs that I'm reading in, and each has a different unique column, so I made a dataframe `df_filenames` that holds the filename pattern `filename_content` and distinct column text `distinct_col`. It works perfectly, and is very simple to maintain. If the column isn't found, or the read has an error (usually due to column count mismatches when it starts reading above the table), then it increases the skip counter and tries again, up to 20 rows:

```
def read_csv_files(folder, df_filenames):
    csv_dict = {}
    for file in os.listdir(folder):
        if file.endswith(".csv"):
            for index, row in df_filenames.iterrows():
                if row['filename_content'] in file:
                    for skip_count in range(20) :
                        try:
                            df_contents = pd.read_csv(folder+file,skiprows=skip_count)
                            if row['distinct_col'] in df_contents.columns :
                                break
                            else :
                                raise ValueError('no date')
                        except :
                            continue
                    csv_dict[file] = {'contents': df_contents}
    return csv_dict
```